# Issue while generating db_schema file for existing module Magento 2.3.1

Tags: magento2.3.1

I have installed fresh Magento 2.2.6 and i have installed two custom modules.

Then i have upgraded the Magento Version to 2.3.1 now i am trying to generate **db_schema** file for those module using below command.

```
php bin/magento setup:install --convert-old-scripts=1
```

Error:

> [Symfony\Component\Console\Exception\RuntimeException]
>
> The "--convert-old-scripts" option does not exist.

Comment: Will those modules have scripts that is InstallSchema

Comment: 1 has InsallSchema,UpgradeSchema, another has only UpgradeData

Answer (score 1):

Run the below command

```
php bin/magento setup:install --convert_old_scripts=1
```

Instead of

```
php bin/magento setup:install --convert-old-scripts=1
```

For more information. [Look at this](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/declarative-schema/migration-commands.html)

Guess this would be issue for your case.

**EDIT :**

Run this command in your root to check the available options there

```
php bin/magento setup:install -h
```

then you'll probably will get this

```
--convert-old-scripts[=CONVERT-OLD-SCRIPTS]
```

so run accordingly of whatever available for your version.

Comment: I have checked with fresh 2.3.1 setup the option convert-old-scripts is displaying but in the upgraded setup there are no convert-old-scripts found.

Comment: Guess the schema already been installed, try fresh magento with uninstalled modules on app/code @AshishViradiya

Answer (score 0):

In order to generate db_schema.xml file for already installed modules follow below link

https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/273981/43981

Comment: Yes the answer is right but the command is not working after upgrade magento version.