# Migrate to declarative schema

Tags: declarative-schema

people. I'm trying to migrate to declarative schema on my module with magento v2.3.1. But when i'm running `php bin/magento setup:install --convert-old-scripts=1` it doesn't generates any db_schema.xml. What i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to remove your module from `setup_module` table and rerun the command.

As far as I understand, Magento analyzes DDL commands called during `setup:upgrade` to generate the schema.

In your case, I assume, the legacy install scripts are not being executed.

Answer (score 2):

In order to migrate your install and upgrade schema of already installed module 
to db_schema.xml follow below steps

- Remove your module entry from `setup_module` table
- Drop all your module tables as mentioned in your install and upgrade schema
- Execute `php bin/magento setup:upgrade --convert-old-scripts=1`